# Make MediaController show without hide

Tags: android, mediacontroller

I try to use MediaController to play music.
I want the MediaController appear until the "back" button is pressed.
Now I have try below code:

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this){
@Override
public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayerControl player) {
super.setMediaPlayer(player);
this.show();
}
@Override
public void show(int timeout) {
super.show(0);
}
//instead of press twice with press once "back" button to back
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
Activity a = (Activity)getContext();
a.finish();
}
return true;
}
};
```

But it still one trouble while the MediaController visible.
When the MediaController appear touch the screen, the MediaController will hide.
I also already try below code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
Log.d("screen","touch");
return true;
}
```

But it did not work.
The string did not show in Logcat.
Anyone has idea to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Override this method also inside media controller

```
@Override
            public void hide() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.show();
            }
```

Comment: @chet using this code media contollers are not hiding but on back press activity is not finishing any idea

Answer (score 8):

If you want to keep the hide() method but not have the controller disappearing every time a control is used :

```
this.mediaController = new MediaController(this){
    @Override
    public void show(int timeout) {
        super.show(0);
    }
};
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Not disabling the hide. Thanks.

Comment: This was two years ago, might be out-dated.
Sorry this wasn't of any help to you.